# Popup model showing empty content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to append an object array to div inside a model popup. The for loop is getting the value but content is empty. How could I append the value of this object array in the provided div inside a popup model.
The code is given below

```
$(function () {
    $(".chkBoxPer").on("click", function () {
        var data = [];
        if ($(".chkBoxPer").is(":checked")) {
            //alert($(".chkBoxPer:checked").closest('tr').find('.txtPer').text());

            data.push({
                name: $(".chkBoxPer:checked").closest('tr').find('.txtPer').text()
               
            });
        }
        console.clear();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});

$('#btnModelPopup').click(function () {
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem("data");
    var content = "";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
        content += "<div" + i + "'></div>";
        
    }
    $("#cascadeValue").append(content);
    $("#idCscade").modal("show");
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop declaration you need to use `data.length` instead of just `data`, and you were also adding the `i` to the div tag which made it look like `<div0></div>` which would not be a valid HTML element. I would advise you to add the `i` as an attribute to the div, for example as an `id` or similar:

```js
let data = '[{"name": "example"}]';
let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);   // parse to JSON notation since data is a string

var content = "";
for (var i = 0; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
    content += '<div id="' + i + '"></div>';
}

console.log(content);
```

Comment: Your `data` type is array while OP `data` is string

Comment: @Justinas Darn, I missed that. I'll edit. Also, I was about to ask you for your example, I believe `"<div" + i + "'></div>"` will produce a non valid element.

Comment: How to put a line </br> break inside the content

Comment: @DotNetCoder You mean like this `content += '<div id="' + i + '">some text<br/>other text</div>';`?

Comment: at this time the data is coming like this - Inpatient( IP) Oupatient (OP) ER (OP)Urgent Care (OP)
i want like after "Inpatient( IP)" 2nd line  Oupatient (OP) and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is string.

You should do `var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem());` and then `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`:

```
        $('#btnModelPopup').click(function () {
            var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("data"));

            var content = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                content += "<div class='div-" + i + "'></div>";
            }

            $("#cascadeValue").append(content);

            $("#idCscade").modal("show");
        });
```